# Twitter4j.getHomeTimeline method not retrieving consitent number of tweets as specified in the count

Tags: android, twitter4j

When i try to pull out twitter status using Twitter4j.getHomeTimeline(), the number of tweet received is not consistent, even though I am setting the count using paging.

For e.g. If  NO_OF_TWEETS is 50, statuses.size() is not always 50.

```
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
        // Access Token
        String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        // Access Token Secret
        String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        ResponseList<Status> statuses = null;


        if(maxId != null) {

            Paging page1 = new Paging();
            page1.setCount(NO_OF_TWEETS);
            page1.setMaxId(maxId);
            statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(page1);

        }else{

            Paging page1 = new Paging();

            page1.setCount(NO_OF_TWEETS);
            page1.setSinceId(sinceId);
            statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(page1);
        }

        Log.d(TAG,"No. of new Statues : "+statuses.size());
```

Comment: I am creating a little twitter app in which I am loading the tweets in a listview and adding "load more items" textview after the list of tweets if there are more tweets available.

Issue is that how can I find out if there are more tweets available as twitter4j.getHometimeline() is sometimes retrieving the less number of tweets than specified in the COUNT even if there a more tweets available. I want to display "load more items" text view only when more tweets are available.